# Banner configuration for heyzap ios sdk

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, banner-ads, heyzap

I am trying to adjust the size of the banners (for ios sdk) on my app using hey zap mediation. Although there is guidance on how to do this on the website, it is not very clear and I am new to coding.

I have tried to follow their instructions but have found no success. I would like to adjust the size of the Admob and Heyzap exchange banner size and need help on the exact code and where to place it .

Here is the code I used

```
" HZBannerAdOptions *options = [[HZBannerAdOptions alloc] init];  

options.admobBannerSize =HZAdMobBannerSizeFlexibleWidthLandscape;  

options.heyzapExchangeBannerSize= HZHeyzapExchangeBannerSizeFlexibleWidthHeight32;

[HZBannerAd placeBannerInView:self.view

position:HZBannerPositionBottom
            options:options

 success:^(HZBannerAd *banner) {

            }
            failure:^(NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"Error = %@",error);
            }
];"
```

The problem is that the right size banner does appear at the bottom but another banner of the wrong (default) size appears over it.

Comment: Please edit your post with this info. Comments don't support formatting

Comment: I have edited the post.